# Meteor.http.call method

Tags: meteor

I am trying to insert data in MongoLab using

```
  if (Meteor.is_server) {
 Meteor.startup(function () {
// code to run on server at startup
 var result = Meteor.http.call("POST",  "url",
 {params:{"name" : "def"},headers:{"content-type":"application/json"}}, function      (error,result) {
              console.log(result);
            });

     });
```

}

I am  getting  error
     data: { message: 'Could not parse JSON, please double-check syntax and encoding:           \nname=def\n ^' }

Comment: can you provide snapshot of error and result parameters of callback function?

Comment: I had replaced the 'params' with 'data'. So now it's working properly

Comment: can you please add your comment as answer, and mark it answered?

Answer (score 6):

Thank you.

The problem solved by replacing 'params' with 'data'.