# Looks like Meteor.http.post is not working properly

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to post on a user's facebook feed from the server side of Meteor app:

```
result = Meteor.http.call 'POST',
    "https://graph.facebook.com/#{facebook_id}/feed?access_token=#{app_access_token}",
    { data: { message: "some message", link: "http://www.somelink.com" } }
```

I got the following as a result:

```
{"statusCode":400,"content":"{\"error\":{\"message\":\"(#100) Missing message or attachment\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":100}}","headers":{"access-control-allow-origin":"*","cache-control":"no-store","content-type":"text/javascript; charset=UTF-8","expires":"Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT","pragma":"no-cache","www-authenticate":"OAuth \"Facebook Platform\" \"invalid_request\" \"(#100) Missing message or attachment\"","x-fb-rev":"710505","x-fb-debug":"doa24fNWaPsogxv4HmXa1/5KA30BBct86VZWVeYsins=","date":"Fri, 11 Jan 2013 13:57:52 GMT","connection":"keep-alive","content-length":"95"},"data":{"error":{"message":"(#100) Missing message or attachment","type":"OAuthException","code":100}},"error":{}}
```

I tried to reproduce this problem in Facebook debugger - I got the same message only if I do not send any parameters in POST body. Could it be the problem of POST implementation in Meteor.http.call?

Comment: Have you tried it with `params` instead of `data`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're sending your data in the HTTP POST request content body `data`, you need to use `params` to pass the correct variables on as postdata

try

```
result = Meteor.http.post(
   "https://graph.facebook.com/#{facebook_id}/feed?access_token=#{app_access_token}",
   { params: { message: "some message", link: "http://www.somelink.com" } } );
```

Also if you're diong this in a `Meteor.methods` stub try using `this.unblock();` so that other operations can occur simultaneously

**Update**: The newer versions of meteor use `HTTP` instead of `Meteor.http`, the code above would go as `HTTP.post` as a drop in replacement.

Comment: Note that sometimes you need to use `data` instead of `params`. See my answer on this SO question. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998140/gmail-rest-api-mark-message-as-read/30201963#30201963)

Comment: Yes, sometimes you need to use data instead of params. See this other example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205270/meteor-http-call-method